# How to align a link icon after the text via CSS?

Tags: html, css, icons

I have a navigation menu with links, before the text link I have an icon, I would like to put this icon after the text  link. The website is here http://www.labella.co.il/.

CSS of the link:

```
.sidebar ul.menu li a {background: url("1-default/bullet.png") no-repeat scroll 0 12px transparent;}
```

Icon image is in `url("1-default/bullet.png")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the changed code to get what you are after:

```
.sidebar ul.menu li a {
    background: url("1-default/bullet.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 12px transparent;
    padding: 10px 22px 10px 0;
}
```

I am swapping the left padding to the right, and pushing the background image across to the right hand side.

Note that I have used `100%` as opposed to a 'magic number' (like the other answers). This means that even if the width changes, the icons will still line up, with no maintenance required!

Answer (score 2):

Change the position of the background image and add some padding so the text won't cover it:

```css
.sidebar ul.menu li a {
    background: url("1-default/bullet.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 12px transparent;
}

.sidebar ul.menu li a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 23px 10px 22px;
    display: block;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: You should use 100% instead of a 'magic number'. This means that it will work no matter the width of the list items, without requiring any changes.

Comment: @joshnh you're right - the 100% is a better option. but if it was you who downvoted greener's and my answer - you're not using the downvotes correctly. It's reserved for *non correct* answers, however both answers are correct and perfectly working ones. Yours just *more* correct

Comment: In my humble opinion, teaching bad practice is almost as bad as an incorrect answer.

Comment: @joshnh Since when using `px` based values on fixed width elements became *"bad practice"*?

Comment: Please read my first comment (pay special attention to 'magic number').

Comment: Please pay special attention to 'fixed width elements' words of my reply. My point is that our answers are *not* wrong and *not* bad practice etc. since they solve the OP's issue. And if you try watch out for potential future problems - you can never predict them all, so based on that your answer could be easily downvoted too. It does anticipate the width change *only* - what about ALL possible changes?

Comment: You seem to be arguing specifics? It is common knowledge that using 'magic numbers' is bad practice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015888/refactor-css-to-eliminate-magic-numbers). That is all I'm talking about. If you would like to discuss it further, I'm happy to talk about it in chat.

Comment: @joshnh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21041/discussion-between-zoltan-toth-and-joshnh)

Answer (score 1):

`background-position` could be changed like:

```
.sidebar ul.menu li a {
  background: url("1-default/bullet.png") no-repeat scroll 202px 12px transparent;
}
```

and then `padding` adjusted to make room for the icon:

```
.sidebar ul.menu li a {
   cursor: pointer;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 10px 22px 10px 0;
   display: block;
   background: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: You should use 100% instead of a 'magic number'. This means that it will work no matter the width of the list items, without requiring any changes.

Comment: Sometimes, it can be good to have more control but 100% is also a valid option :)

Comment: In this case, if you wanted more control, then using padding on the list item would make much more sense.